Helping willing people overstay their visa, cross borders illegally, get work permits: which crime is this?
I am trying to figure out what this type of crime is.
Some people immediately call this "human trafficking", but according to wikipedia, human trafficking involves some kind of coercion and victims:

Lets imagine the following people who are knowing or unknowing part of a scheme:

Guest worker from Asia, pays a sum to a recruiting agency in Asia
European recruiting agency is getting a cut from the asian agency, for finding work for their candidates
Hotel in Europe takes these seasonal workers to work for them, on short term legal work permits
Some shady person organizes these guest workers, who have Schengen visas to travel to another country (unclear if this happens legally or ilegally), which needs workers, another recruiting agency helps them get long term work permits in this other country.

I know this is happening for a fact and my question is, which of these parties is committing which crime? The end result is people having a real long term work permit. They also have real geographically unlimited schengen visas when they come as seasonal workers. Lets forget the intricacies of Schengen law and EU. Only focus on the question what this thing is called and can it be described as human trafficking?
I understand that people giving consent under threat is no real consent, but these people actively find a recruiting agency, pay them money, get to Europe, pay some other agency money, etc.
If this is not human trafficking, what kind of other crime is it?
Assume these people are not threthened or coerced, there is no forced or illegal labor, there is no prostitution, etc. There are cases of fraud, but its not systemic. I am also not involved with the workers directly, I do not make any promises to them, I do not take payments from them, etc. However I do get a payment from their agency.
Lets assume these people don't have Schengen visas, but cross the border illegally, then work illegally or overstay their visas. Would that make it human trafficking? Its still not coerced after all.

Why do you think anyone is committing any crimes in this situation? Where's the threat?

@littleadv I personally don't think so, but lawyers have warned my business partner to stay away from asian guest workers and he told me we are going to jail for human trafficking because high number of people = human trafficking. I am trying to understand what kind of crime if any this is. Lets assume they cross the border illegally or overstay their visas or other such things (which I don't think is the case but maybe it is). For example the american coyotes helping people cross a border - they also don't work with force (I think) but are described as human traffickers?

American coyotes help violate immigration law, which is a crime in the US. But where is the violation in your story? Being a placement agency is not a crime

@littleadv I am not exactly sure. This is what Im trying to figure out. They could argue that my agency is feeding people into coyote organizations, they could argue there is no way I don't know its happening or something. I don't have contact with such people but not sure if me unwillingly helping them counts. Do I need to stop my business because down the line people commit crimes (maybe).

You need to talk to a lawyer about the specifics of your situation.

@user1721135 "lawyers have warned my business partner": ask them what crime you'd be commiting and which of your acts are elements of that crime.  But it's also possible that nothing you're thinking of doing is a crime but that it is likely to appear to be a crime and the lawyers think that it will be difficult to defend against those accusations in court. E.g. in many systems, theft requires an intention to deprive a property owner of some property permanently, but if you take a watch, it's hard to rebut the assertion that you intended to keep it, even if you genuinely planned to return it.

If they get their subsequent work permits legally and their employment terms are compliant with labor laws in the second country and there's truly no coercion, then it's hard to imagine how any of this could be a crime.  But if the fact pattern is similar to a well known exploitative or illegal scheme to hire foreign workers then it may be difficult to prove that in your case it isn't.  Another thought: if the subsequent employer is so eager to hire these people, and is doing so legally with proper permits, why not have them leave the Schengen area to get their documents, and then return?

@phoog I don't know exactly how it works, I can only speculate. Lawyers warned me that its human trafficking if we have a high % of workers who dont return. I think they enter a country, where its easy to enter from asia, then go to another, higher paid country, where they can get a work permit easily, if they are there, but they wouldn't easily get it if they are in asia. Something like that. No idea if its required to leave schengen and what exactly the crime is. There is also politics involved, some countries try to limit immigration. I think they may overdo it a little with the warnings.

These foreigners don’t work and take our jobs away - except these foreigners do work and nobody native wants the job. So hard to see a crime.

You did not highlight the words "for the purposes of exploitation" in the quoted passage, which are a vital part of the definition. And in the scenario described, that is what makes the difference between human trafficking versus simply using the immigration/visa system as intended.
The UK is not part of Schengen, but has implemented the Palermo Protocol in the Modern Slavery Act 2015 and the Human Trafficking and Exploitation (Scotland) Act 2015. MSA section 2 and HTE(S)A section 1 contain a similar definition of the offence of trafficking, in the same terms as in the Protocol. Both require that the recruitment, transportation, etc. be "with a view" to someone "being exploited". The definition of "exploited" (section 3 of both Acts) encompasses:

Being subject to slavery, servitude or forced labour - contravening Article 4 of the European Convention on Human Rights;
Being a victim of certain sexual offences, including being compelled into prostitution;
Being encouraged, required or expected to be involved in offences relating to the illegal removal of organs;
Being subject to force, threats or deception in order to provide services or benefits to another.

If these conditions are not met then the conduct is not trafficking. For the scenario in the question, the factual circumstances might or might not support the presence of force or deception, or characteristics of the work which bring it within the prohibition of Article 4.
Aside from this, it's possible that other immigration offences could be being committed. Some relevant ones are -

illegal entry, overstaying, failure to comply with conditions (Immigration Act 1971 s. 24); illegal working (Asylum and Immigration Act 1996 s.8, Immigration, Nationality and Asylum Act 2006 s.21)
deception (Immigration Act 1971 s. 24A(1)), failure to provide documents (s. 26(1)(b)), making a false statement (s. 26(1)(c)), fraud or forgery in general
providing immigration advice or services as a non-qualified person, or offering to do so (Immigration and Asylum Act 1999 ss.91(1) and 92B(1))
"facilitating the commission of a breach of immigration law" (Immigration Act 1971 s.25)

In the example of people who "cross the border illegally, then work illegally or overstay their visas", it's a given that the people themselves are committing certain offences as above. Someone in an agency who is helping them to do so, or is aware that this conduct is going on and continues to support it, is very much the target of the facilitation offence mentioned. Additionally, if an agency is acting as a sponsor, there are various regulatory requirements for provision of information and actually carrying out the sponsorship, with penalties for not doing so.

Thanks that sounds right, EU also has "facilitation of breach of immigration law" so it makes sense.

The crime (if any) is called people smuggling
If, as you say in the title, someone assisted someone else to cross an international border unlawfully, then the person who crosses is an illegal entrant, and the person who helped is a people smuggler. Human trafficking is a different crime.
In australia, there are various offences under the Migration Act 1958 that fall within the catch-all term.

Thanks, I didn't know this was a separate thing. But is this a law or just an expression? Is this covered by "facilitation of breach of immigration law" or its something else?

@user1721135 It looks like it's just a common term. But in general, facilitating a crime is usually a crime as well, as an accessory. E.g. the getaway driver in a bank robbery is an accessory to the robbery.

@Barmar what if you are a taxi driver in a bad neighborhood and you think many of your clients are drug dealers, but you are not sure. I guess it would depend on if you charge them extra which would indicate you are part of it.

@user1721135 In general you have to know you're involved in a crime. Just because there are lots of drug dealers in a neighborhood doesn't mean any particular customer is one.

@user1721135 OTOH, when Texas SB8 was passed, people worried that Uber drivers could be sued for driving women to abortion clinics.

@Barmar, no, you don’t have to know you are committing a crime, you just have to intentionally be doing whatever it is that constitutes the crime. Saying “I didn’t know killing people was illegal” Is not a defence even if it’s true.

@DaleM That's obviously not what I meant. The taxi driver doesn't know that they're involved in a robbery at all. They're just picking up a fare.

@Barmar again wrong - there are plenty of unwitting drug mules in jails all over the world.

@DaleM Legitimately, or something like the plot of "Brokedown Palace"?

The unwilling drug mules are travelling alone with drugs not with a person with drugs on him.

@user1721135 unwitting, not unwilling, but your point still stands: having a passenger who is carrying drugs is not the same as carrying drugs, especially if you are in the business of carrying passengers.
